# How to join when building Predicate(s), but without having a JPAQuery instance

Tags: java, querydsl

When building a Predicate for the Entity Book, I would like to be able 
to left join on Category (ManyToMany) to add a AND Predicate on Category.
I could simply achieve that if I have the JPAQuery instance :

```
if (catId != null) {
    jpaQuery.leftJoin(book.categories, category);
    jpaQuery.where(category.id.eq(catId).or(category.parentCategory.id.eq(catId)));
}
```

But when building Predicates I don't have yet the JPAQuery.
So for the Predicate itself I could do :

```
booleanBuilder.and(category.id.eq(this.categoryId).or(category.parentCategory.id.eq(this.categoryId)));
```

But for the leftjoin how to proceed without the jpaQuery instance ?

Comment: Any news regarding this one? I'm searching all over the place for an elegant solution of Joining Fetching without too much hassle... apparently Spring Data didn't think of use cases more complex then a single "select from where scenario" like shown on their basic examples...

Comment: yep i found a solution : i coded an extension to spring-data interface : public interface TworkQueryDslRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {)  and added a prep method : JPAQuery createQuery();   and  all executing methods with a new param typed JPAQuery : ex age<T> findAll(JPAQuery jpaQuery, Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable);  The goal is to have the Repo build and give me the JPAQuery so i could fetch. And Second phase, i can invoke an almost standard repo API but giving back the JPAQuery as first param in my case. I should make a PullResquest sometimes

Comment: @GauthierPeel could you please elaborate on your solution, maybe in the form of an answer? It would be really helpful!

Comment: now in spring boot 2.6+ we have a feature for that. Even if it's a new feature and not all seems to works:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71100160/fetching-and-paging-in-the-same-time-with-fetchablefluentquery-and-querydslpredi

Answer (score 1):

You need the Query to declare the left join in Querydsl. If this is Spring Data related, they might come up with an API level solution.

book.categories.any() can be used instead of category, but it is serialized differently to JPQL, with a subquery instead of a join.

Comment: I'm trying to do this with Spring Data, thanks for the pointer that this is a problem with their API.